# Generating identical pseudorandom numbers on client and server

Tags: javascript, c#, random

I have a web application using JavaScript on the client side and C# on the server side.  I need to be able to generate sets pseudorandom numbers - given a shared seed - that are identical on the client and server sides.  Is there a standard way of doing this?  Obviously it's no good using the built-in PRNG libraries for the respective languages because their algorithms are going to differ.

I don't want to use a server endpoint to provide the client with the random numbers because my client application requires quick responses and that would add latency.  It would *work* but wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Why the server doesn't return those random numbers? Then there's no need to generate them twice and hope that they are same.

Comment: Performance.  Avoiding the client having to go to the server repeatedly.  I'm coding a game that requires quick response times so it's much better if the client can generate what the server would rather than having to actually ask the server,

Comment: You can write down a [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with same factors on both side.

Comment: @Jez: well, then i don't understand why the server needs to generate it as well. Can't  the client provide it if needed?

Comment: @TimSchmelter The client is vulnerable to being modified, and therefore a player could generate whatever number they want to give themselves an advantage. The server needs to independently generate the random number itself to ensure that the correct algorithm has actually been used.

Comment: @Jez: why is performance critical here? Do you need to generate the numbers often, not only once at the beginning of the game? Maybe you can load them asynchronously from the server in background.

Comment: Yeah, that would work.  But it just seems to me like a bunch of unnecessary work to keep connecting to the server in the background when they could just use the same PRNG algorithm and have no need for any network.

Comment: Assuming that you roll your own PRNG (which is fairly straightforward) for both C# and Javascript, then how are the client and server coordinating which iteration of the PRNG to employ, to ensure that both sides are performing the necessary synchronized calculations without having to communicate on this matter?

Comment: A shared seed which is sent as part of the game state each turn is what I'd envisioned.

Comment: @Jez to further clarify my question, how does the client and server each know the current game state turn?  Eg, what's to prevent the client from being 10 turns ahead of the server, and the server is using the wrong generated random value?  That is, it seems there must still be some type of communication between the client and server to determine the game state turn being processed...

Comment: Yes there is, on each turn updated info is sent.  But it can't predict how many random numbers the client may need at that point, and I don't want some fudge like "send 100 and hope it's enough", it feels hacky to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I've come to the conclusion that the only really reliable way I could get exactly the same PRNG on both the server and client side is to use the same language on both sides - for example C# using Blazor on the client-side and C#.NET on the server-side - and to create a class in that language that has an identical implementation for the server-side and client-side code, which would get shared.

A good class to copy/paste for such an implementation would probably be the `XoshiroImpl` random number generator class which seems to be the [latest PRNG implementation being used by .NET core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3689fbec921418e496962dc0ee252bdc9eafa3de/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.cs).

As it is I'm using JS for the client and C# for the server, so I had to solve the problem in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a javascript implementation of the C version of [xorshift128+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift+).  Per the wikipedia article, the xorshift128+ pseudo random number generator (PRNG) passes [BigCrush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01) (empirical randomness testing).

Note that xorshift128+ is used by major browsers when implementing [Math.random](https://v8.dev/blog/math-random?showComment=1450389868643#c2004131565745698275), so it's a solid algorithm, although not crypto solid...

Note also that the local variables within method `nextValue` make use of a BigUint64Array, as this automatically reduces any intermediate results to 64 bits.

```js
class XorShift128 {

  #state;
  
  static bitMask64 = ( 1n << 64n ) - 1n;
  static bitMask32 = ( 1n << 32n ) - 1n
  
  constructor( uint128Seed ) {
    this.#state = new BigUint64Array( [ ( uint128Seed >> 64n ) & XorShift128.bitMask64, uint128Seed & XorShift128.bitMask64 ] );
  }
  
  get nextValue() {
    let r = new BigUint64Array( this.#state );
    // C version t = r[0], s = r[1]
    this.#state[ 0 ] = r[ 1 ];
    r[ 0 ] ^= r[ 0 ] << 23n;
    r[ 0 ] ^= r[ 0 ] >> 18n;
    r[ 0 ] ^= r[ 1 ] ^ ( r[ 1 ] >> 5n );
    this.#state[ 1 ] = r[ 0 ];
    return Number( ( r[ 0 ] + r[ 1 ] ) & XorShift128.bitMask32 );
  }

}

console.log( `Set the seed to 0x8a5cd789635d2dff121fd2155c472f96n and generate 5 values...` );
let PRNG0 = new XorShift128( 0x8a5cd789635d2dff121fd2155c472f96n );
for ( let i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
  console.log( PRNG0.nextValue );
}

console.log( `Let's do it again...` );

let PRNG1 = new XorShift128( 0x8a5cd789635d2dff121fd2155c472f96n );
for ( let i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
  console.log( PRNG1.nextValue );
}
```

For completeness sake, here's the same algorithm in C.

```
//gcc 7.4.0

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    
struct xorshift128p_state {
    uint64_t x[2];
};

/* The state must be seeded so that it is not all zero */
uint64_t xorshift128p(struct xorshift128p_state *state)
{
    uint64_t t = state->x[0];
    uint64_t const s = state->x[1];
    state->x[0] = s;
    t ^= t << 23;
    t ^= t >> 18;
    t ^= s ^ (s >> 5);
    state->x[1] = t;
    return t + s;
}

main() {
    struct xorshift128p_state seed;
    seed.x[0] = 0x8a5cd789635d2dff;
    seed.x[1] = 0x121fd2155c472f96;
    
    uint64_t bitMask32 = ( 1ULL << 32 ) - 1ULL;
    
    int i;
    for ( i =0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        uint64_t rv = xorshift128p( &seed );
        printf( "%ld\n", rv & bitMask32 );
    }
    
}
```

[C Code Snippet](https://rextester.com/YUKCRV17853)

Answer (score 0):

Add an API endpoint on the server in c# to return individual or an array of random numbers, then call that from the client.

> calls to the server do not have to be inefficient, depending on your logic and the frequency of the call, it might even make sense to call this from the server, especially if consistency of the values is so important, this might be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), what is the frequency of the calls, what is the highest latency that you can tolerate and what type of response times are you recording from your implementation.

Yes, there is a standard solution to problems like this (replicating logic in the client and the server) and that is to use the same random number generator algorithm and the same *seed* value. This is for instance how we can replay specific hands in card games.

A pure C# solution that allows you to use the same code in the client and the server would be to consider Blazor instead of javascript. Other solutions would be to implement your own algorithm or to find another one that has been ported to both C# and javascript.

Comment: Yes I considered that, but it would require the client frequently going to the server for random numbers so performance-wise, I'd rather avoid the client having to explicitly get them from the server.

Comment: So return an array of significant length to reduce this. Blazor is a legitimate solution because it is the same random logic in the client and the server... But why server at all if the number is generated on the client?

Comment: The client is vulnerable to being modified, and therefore a player could generate whatever number they want to give themselves an advantage.  The server needs to independently generate the random number itself to ensure that the correct algorithm has actually been used.